# Can we find sums for $\int_1^{\infty }e^{\pi i t} \left(t^{1/t}-1\right) \, dt?$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

The MRB constant is the sum of the series https://oeis.org/A037077.

cf. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MRBConstant.html

The MRB consstant (CMRB)
$$=\sum _k^{\infty } \left((2 k)^{\frac{1}{2 k}}-(2 k-1)^{\frac{1}{2 k-1}}\right)=\sum _m^{\infty } (-1)^m \left(m^{1/m}-1\right)$$

@Dark Malthorp, found integrals for it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564705/what-are-some-working-models-that-are-a-fit-the-formula-for-the-mrb-constant) using the Abel-Plana formula.
$$\begin{eqnarray}
C_{MRB} &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(1 - (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right) \\&=& \frac{i}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{(-i t+1)^{\frac{1}{-i t+1}} - (i t+1)^{\frac{1}{i t+1}}}{\sinh{\pi t}} dt \\&=& \int_0^\infty\frac{\Im\left((1+i t)^{\frac{1}{1+i t}}\right)}{\sinh \pi t} dt\\&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1})^{1/(x^2+1)} \exp\left(\frac{x\arctan{x}}{x^2+1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\arctan(x) - x\log\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}\right)}{\sinh \pi x}dx
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Hence my new question: is there a sum using the  the Abel-Plana formula in reverse so-to speak for its integrated analog, M2
$$=\int_1^{\infty }e^{\pi i t} \left(t^{1/t}-1\right) \, dt?$$

$\lim_{x->\infty}\int_1^{2x }e^{\pi i t} \left(t^{1/t}\right) \, dt=M2+-21/\pi.$ And $|M2+-21/\pi| $ is the integral of https://oeis.org/A157852, where a few other people have added their toughts.

Background and motivation along with notes from of years of research can be found throughout [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1323951?) Wolfram Community discussion.

RAHUL said a power series expansion might be useful in this case, so I came up with
$$M2=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{i}{\pi }\right)^{1-n}\left( G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1 \\
 0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-i \pi  G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1 \\
 -1,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-\pi ^2 G_{4,5}^{5,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1 \\
 -2,0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)+i \pi ^3 G_{5,6}^{6,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1,1 \\
 -3,0,0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)+\pi ^4 G_{6,7}^{7,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1,1,1 \\
 -4,0,0,0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-i \pi ^5 G_{7,8}^{8,0}\left(-i \pi \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 \\
 -5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-...\right)$$

As found by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564705/what-are-some-working-models-that-are-a-fit-the-formula-for-the-mrb-constant) Wolfram Cloud notebook.
As shown in [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1323951?) Wolfram Cloud notebook.
As published in [this](https://oeis.org/A157852/a157852_12.pdf) OEIS document.

Concluding what I know,
[image]

In traditional form,

$$M2=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{i}{\pi }\right)^{1-n}\left(\text G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(^{1;\underbrace {x,…,x}_n}_{1-n,0; \underbrace {x,…,x}_n}\bigg|-\pi i\right)\right).$$

So, I found one that way, but believe there are more, because there are dozens of forms of the MRB constant all proved at https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/214522-Formulas-For-The-MRB-Constant

Please note that Tyma Gaidash provided a formula from a reliable source, although not certain if conditions met. If anyone can show it working or not, and offer a proof that it or a variant of it leads to a sum for $\int_1^{\infty }e^{\pi i t} \left(t^{1/t}-1\right) \, dt,$ I will set up another bounty to reward such a worthy answer. (The goal here is to find a formula for that integral that involves integration, to the least amount as possible. (Which is an improvement from defining MeigerG in terms of integrals.)

Please ask questions if you've got them!

Comment: Do you want a sum only using Abel plana formula or is it optional. Because power series expansions might be uselful in this case.

Comment: Is that just the integral of all the terms of the ps of the integrand? If they all can be put together in a summation,  that might fit the bill nicely.

Comment: Also the Meijer G terms can be in [alternate forms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%28%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%7D%2C%7B%7B0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D%2C-pi+i%29) in terms of simpler functions like in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s try using [Slater’s Theorem](http://elffer.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/7/8/13783472/meijer_g-function_-_wikipedia_the_free_encyclopedia.pdf) to evaluate the Meijer G function which does fit the necessary conditions for using the formula. The simplest example is [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%28%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%7D%2C%7B%7B0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D%2C-pi+i%29) for the $\,^{3,0}_{2,3}$ case. Here is your general formula:

$$\text G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(^{1;\underbrace {1,…,1}_n}_{1-n,0; \underbrace {0,…,0}_n}\bigg|-\pi i\right)=\sum_{h=1}^{n+2}\frac{\prod\limits_{h\ne j=1}^{n+2}\Gamma(b_j-b_h)\prod\limits_{j=1}^0\Gamma(b_h-a_j+1)(-\pi i)^{b_h}}{\prod\limits_{j=n+3}^{n+2}\Gamma(b_h-b_j+1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n+1}\Gamma(a_j-b_h)}\,_{n+1}\text F_{n+1}\left(b_h-a_{n+1}+1;b_h-b_{n+2}+1;\pi i\right),a_{n+1}=\{1-n,0, \underbrace {0,…,0}_n\},b_{n+2}=\{1, \underbrace {1,…,1}_n\}$$

where $b_h-b_{n+2}+1,h\ne n+2$ *I will work on simplifying this result* to see if anything interesting comes up. I am also new to Slater’s Theorem, for the $p=n+1,q=n+2,p<q$ version, so if this is the wrong formula, then please tell me. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Special cases with the [Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/), [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/), and more:

$$\text G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(^{1,1}_{0,0,0}\big|-\pi i\right)=\frac12\left(\gamma^2-i\gamma \pi-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\ln^2(\pi)+2\gamma\ln(\pi)-i\pi\ln(\pi)\right)+\pi i\,_3\text F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;\pi i)$$

Let’s try the next case:

$$\text G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(^{1,1,1}_{-1,0,0,0}\big|\pi i\right)=\sum_{h=1}^3\frac{\prod\limits_{h\ne j=1}^{3}\Gamma(b_j-b_h)\prod\limits_{j=1}^0\Gamma(b_h-a_j+1)(-\pi i)^{b_h}}{\prod\limits_{j=5}^4\Gamma(b_h-b_j+1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^3\Gamma(a_j-b_h)}\,_3\text F_3(b_h-a_3+1,b_{j\ne4}-b_4+1),a_3=\{1,1,1\},b_4=\{-1,0,0,0\}\mathop=^? \sum_{h=1}^3\frac{\prod\limits_{h\ne j=1}^{3}\Gamma(b_j-b_h)(-\pi i)^{b_h}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^3\Gamma(a_j-b_h)}\,_3\text F_3(b_h-a_3+1,b_{j\ne4}-b_4+1) $$

After some experimentation and learning the indices of the Meijer G function, here is the copyable code for the simplified $\,^{4,0}_{3,4}$ case where appears the [Trigonometric Integral functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) and [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and *note that “gamma” is the Euler Gamm/ Euler-Mascheroni Constant*:

`-i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π) + i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + Ci(π) + i Si(π) + ζ(3)/3 - gamma ^2/2 + gamma ^3/6 - i/π - (i π)/2 + (i gamma π)/2 - 1/4 i gamma ^2 π + π^2/24 - ( gamma π^2)/24 - (i π^3)/48 + (log^3(π))/6 - (log^2(π))/2 + 1/2 gamma log^2(π) - 1/4 i π log^2(π) - gamma log(π) + 1/2 gamma ^2 log(π) + 1/2 i π log(π) - 1/2 i gamma π log(π) - 1/24 π^2 log(π)`

Here is the simplified $\,^{5,0}_{4,5}$ case with copyable code:

`7/8 i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π) - 3/4 i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + 1/2 i π _5 F_5(1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) - (15 Ci(π))/16 - (15 i Si(π))/16 + 1/12 ζ(3) (-3 + 2 gamma - i π + 2 log(π)) - 9/32 + (3 gamma )/16 + (7 gamma ^2)/16 - gamma ^3/8 + gamma ^4/48 + 1/(16 π^2) + (15 i)/(16 π) + (27 i π)/32 - (7 i gamma π)/16 + 3/16 i gamma ^2 π - 1/24 i gamma ^3 π - (7 π^2)/192 + ( gamma π^2)/32 - ( gamma ^2 π^2)/96 + (i π^3)/64 - 1/96 i gamma π^3 - π^4/1280 + (log^4(π))/48 - (log^3(π))/8 + 1/12 gamma log^3(π) - 1/24 i π log^3(π) + (7 log^2(π))/16 - 3/8 gamma log^2(π) + 1/8 gamma ^2 log^2(π) + 3/16 i π log^2(π) - 1/8 i gamma π log^2(π) - 1/96 π^2 log^2(π) + 3/32 (3 - 2 gamma + i π - 2 log(π)) + 15/32 (-log(π) - (i π)/2) + (9 log(π))/8 + 7/8 gamma log(π) - 3/8 gamma ^2 log(π) + 1/12 gamma ^3 log(π) - 7/16 i π log(π) + 3/8 i gamma π log(π) - 1/8 i gamma ^2 π log(π) + 1/32 π^2 log(π) - 1/48 gamma π^2 log(π) - 1/96 i π^3 log(π) - 15/32 (log(π) + (i π)/2)`

Here is the more complicated simplification for the $\,^{6,0}_{5,6}$ case with code:

`-(575 i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π))/1296 + 85/216 i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π) - 11/36 i π _5 F_5(1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + 1/6 i π _6 F_6(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + (3661 Ci(π))/7776 + (3661 i Si(π))/7776 + ζ(5)/30 + ζ(3) (85/648 - (11 gamma )/108 + gamma ^2/36 + (11 i π)/216 - (i gamma π)/36 - π^2/432 + (log^2(π))/36 - (11 log(π))/108 + 1/18 gamma log(π) - 1/36 i π log(π)) - (575 gamma ^2)/2592 + (85 gamma ^3)/1296 - (11 gamma ^4)/864 + gamma ^5/720 + i/(243 π^3) - 211/(7776 π^2) - (3661 i)/(7776 π) - (3661 i π)/7776 + (575 i gamma π)/2592 - 85/864 i gamma ^2 π + 11/432 i gamma ^3 π - 1/288 i gamma ^4 π + (575 π^2)/31104 - (85 gamma π^2)/5184 + (11 gamma ^2 π^2)/1728 - ( gamma ^3 π^2)/864 - (85 i π^3)/10368 + (11 i gamma π^3)/1728 - 1/576 i gamma ^2 π^3 + (11 π^4)/23040 - ( gamma π^4)/3840 - (19 i π^5)/69120 + (log^5(π))/720 - (11 log^4(π))/864 + 1/144 gamma log^4(π) - 1/288 i π log^4(π) + (85 log^3(π))/1296 - 11/216 gamma log^3(π) + 1/72 gamma ^2 log^3(π) + 11/432 i π log^3(π) - 1/72 i gamma π log^3(π) - 1/864 π^2 log^3(π) - (575 log^2(π))/2592 + 85/432 gamma log^2(π) - 11/144 gamma ^2 log^2(π) + 1/72 gamma ^3 log^2(π) - 85/864 i π log^2(π) + 11/144 i gamma π log^2(π) - 1/48 i gamma ^2 π log^2(π) + (11 π^2 log^2(π))/1728 - 1/288 gamma π^2 log^2(π) - 1/576 i π^3 log^2(π) - (3661 (-log(π) - (i π)/2))/15552 - (3661 log(π))/7776 - (575 gamma log(π))/1296 + 85/432 gamma ^2 log(π) - 11/216 gamma ^3 log(π) + 1/144 gamma ^4 log(π) + (575 i π log(π))/2592 - 85/432 i gamma π log(π) + 11/144 i gamma ^2 π log(π) - 1/72 i gamma ^3 π log(π) - (85 π^2 log(π))/5184 + 11/864 gamma π^2 log(π) - 1/288 gamma ^2 π^2 log(π) + (11 i π^3 log(π))/1728 - 1/288 i gamma π^3 log(π) - (π^4 log(π))/3840 + (3661 (log(π) + (i π)/2))/15552`

Here is the code for the $\,^{7,0}_{6,7}$ case:

`(76111 gamma ^2)/995328 - (5845 gamma ^3)/248832 + (415 gamma ^4)/82944 - (5 gamma ^5)/6912 + gamma ^6/17280 - 1/(4096 π^4) - (3367 i)/(2985984 π^3) + 39193/(5971968 π^2) + (952525 i)/(5971968 π) + (952525 i π)/5971968 - (76111 i gamma π)/995328 + (5845 i gamma ^2 π)/165888 - (415 i gamma ^3 π)/41472 + (25 i gamma ^4 π)/13824 - (i gamma ^5 π)/5760 - (76111 π^2)/11943936 + (5845 gamma π^2)/995328 - (415 gamma ^2 π^2)/165888 + (25 gamma ^3 π^2)/41472 - ( gamma ^4 π^2)/13824 + (5845 i π^3)/1990656 - (415 i gamma π^3)/165888 + (25 i gamma ^2 π^3)/27648 - (i gamma ^3 π^3)/6912 - (83 π^4)/442368 + (5 gamma π^4)/36864 - ( gamma ^2 π^4)/30720 + (95 i π^5)/663552 - (19 i gamma π^5)/276480 - (79 π^6)/23224320 - (952525 Ci(π))/5971968 + (76111 i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π))/497664 - (5845 i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/41472 + (415 i π _5 F_5(1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/3456 - 25/288 i π _6 F_6(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + 1/24 i π _7 F_7(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + (952525 (-(i π)/2 - log(π)))/11943936 + (952525 log(π))/5971968 + (76111 gamma log(π))/497664 - (5845 gamma ^2 log(π))/82944 + (415 gamma ^3 log(π))/20736 - (25 gamma ^4 log(π))/6912 + ( gamma ^5 log(π))/2880 - (76111 i π log(π))/995328 + (5845 i gamma π log(π))/82944 - (415 i gamma ^2 π log(π))/13824 + (25 i gamma ^3 π log(π))/3456 - (i gamma ^4 π log(π))/1152 + (5845 π^2 log(π))/995328 - (415 gamma π^2 log(π))/82944 + (25 gamma ^2 π^2 log(π))/13824 - ( gamma ^3 π^2 log(π))/3456 - (415 i π^3 log(π))/165888 + (25 i gamma π^3 log(π))/13824 - (i gamma ^2 π^3 log(π))/2304 + (5 π^4 log(π))/36864 - ( gamma π^4 log(π))/15360 - (19 i π^5 log(π))/276480 + (76111 log^2(π))/995328 - (5845 gamma log^2(π))/82944 + (415 gamma ^2 log^2(π))/13824 - (25 gamma ^3 log^2(π))/3456 + ( gamma ^4 log^2(π))/1152 + (5845 i π log^2(π))/165888 - (415 i gamma π log^2(π))/13824 + (25 i gamma ^2 π log^2(π))/2304 - 1/576 i gamma ^3 π log^2(π) - (415 π^2 log^2(π))/165888 + (25 gamma π^2 log^2(π))/13824 - ( gamma ^2 π^2 log^2(π))/2304 + (25 i π^3 log^2(π))/27648 - (i gamma π^3 log^2(π))/2304 - (π^4 log^2(π))/30720 - (5845 log^3(π))/248832 + (415 gamma log^3(π))/20736 - (25 gamma ^2 log^3(π))/3456 + 1/864 gamma ^3 log^3(π) - (415 i π log^3(π))/41472 + (25 i gamma π log^3(π))/3456 - 1/576 i gamma ^2 π log^3(π) + (25 π^2 log^3(π))/41472 - ( gamma π^2 log^3(π))/3456 - (i π^3 log^3(π))/6912 + (415 log^4(π))/82944 - (25 gamma log^4(π))/6912 + ( gamma ^2 log^4(π))/1152 + (25 i π log^4(π))/13824 - (i gamma π log^4(π))/1152 - (π^2 log^4(π))/13824 - (5 log^5(π))/6912 + ( gamma log^5(π))/2880 - (i π log^5(π))/5760 + (log^6(π))/17280 - (952525 ((i π)/2 + log(π)))/11943936 - (952525 i Si(π))/5971968 + (-5845/124416 + (415 gamma )/10368 - (25 gamma ^2)/1728 + gamma ^3/432 - (415 i π)/20736 + (25 i gamma π)/1728 - 1/288 i gamma ^2 π + (25 π^2)/20736 - ( gamma π^2)/1728 - (i π^3)/3456 + (415 log(π))/10368 - 25/864 gamma log(π) + 1/144 gamma ^2 log(π) + (25 i π log(π))/1728 - 1/144 i gamma π log(π) - (π^2 log(π))/1728 - (25 log^2(π))/1728 + 1/144 gamma log^2(π) - 1/288 i π log^2(π) + (log^3(π))/432) ζ(3) + ζ(3)^2/432 + (-5/288 + gamma /120 - (i π)/240 + log(π)/120) ζ(5)`

Here is the code for the $\,^{8,0}_{7,8}$:

`8985658285433/6046617600000000 - (65588746609 (137/60 - gamma ))/100776960000000 - (65588746609 gamma )/100776960000000 - (3673451957 gamma ^2)/186624000000 + (58067611 gamma ^3)/9331200000 - (874853 gamma ^4)/622080000 + (12019 gamma ^5)/51840000 - (137 gamma ^6)/5184000 + gamma ^7/604800 - i/(78125 π^5) + 61741/(1280000000 π^4) + (487056529 i)/(2799360000000 π^3) - 6168915439/(5598720000000 π^2) - (226576032859 i)/(5598720000000 π) - (1618229687263 i π)/40310784000000 + (3673451957 i gamma π)/186624000000 - (58067611 i gamma ^2 π)/6220800000 + (874853 i gamma ^3 π)/311040000 - (12019 i gamma ^4 π)/20736000 + (137 i gamma ^5 π)/1728000 - (i gamma ^6 π)/172800 + (3673451957 π^2)/2239488000000 - (58067611 gamma π^2)/37324800000 + (874853 gamma ^2 π^2)/1244160000 - (12019 gamma ^3 π^2)/62208000 + (137 gamma ^4 π^2)/4147200 - ( gamma ^5 π^2)/345600 - (58067611 i π^3)/74649600000 + (874853 i gamma π^3)/1244160000 - (12019 i gamma ^2 π^3)/41472000 + (137 i gamma ^3 π^3)/2073600 - (i gamma ^4 π^3)/138240 + (874853 π^4)/16588800000 - (12019 gamma π^4)/276480000 + (137 gamma ^2 π^4)/9216000 - ( gamma ^3 π^4)/460800 - (228361 i π^5)/4976640000 + (2603 i gamma π^5)/82944000 - (19 i gamma ^2 π^5)/2764800 + (10823 π^6)/6967296000 - (79 gamma π^6)/116121600 - (11 i π^7)/9289728 + (226576032859 Ci(π))/5598720000000 - (3673451957 i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π))/93312000000 + (58067611 i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/1555200000 - (874853 i π _5 F_5(1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/25920000 + (12019 i π _6 F_6(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/432000 - (137 i π _7 F_7(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/7200 + 1/120 i π _8 F_8(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) - (226576032859 (-(i π)/2 - log(π)))/11197440000000 - (4143957338071 log(π))/100776960000000 - (3673451957 gamma log(π))/93312000000 + (58067611 gamma ^2 log(π))/3110400000 - (874853 gamma ^3 log(π))/155520000 + (12019 gamma ^4 log(π))/10368000 - (137 gamma ^5 log(π))/864000 + ( gamma ^6 log(π))/86400 + (3673451957 i π log(π))/186624000000 - (58067611 i gamma π log(π))/3110400000 + (874853 i gamma ^2 π log(π))/103680000 - (12019 i gamma ^3 π log(π))/5184000 + (137 i gamma ^4 π log(π))/345600 - (i gamma ^5 π log(π))/28800 - (58067611 π^2 log(π))/37324800000 + (874853 gamma π^2 log(π))/622080000 - (12019 gamma ^2 π^2 log(π))/20736000 + (137 gamma ^3 π^2 log(π))/1036800 - ( gamma ^4 π^2 log(π))/69120 + (874853 i π^3 log(π))/1244160000 - (12019 i gamma π^3 log(π))/20736000 + (137 i gamma ^2 π^3 log(π))/691200 - (i gamma ^3 π^3 log(π))/34560 - (12019 π^4 log(π))/276480000 + (137 gamma π^4 log(π))/4608000 - ( gamma ^2 π^4 log(π))/153600 + (2603 i π^5 log(π))/82944000 - (19 i gamma π^5 log(π))/1382400 - (79 π^6 log(π))/116121600 - (3673451957 log^2(π))/186624000000 + (58067611 gamma log^2(π))/3110400000 - (874853 gamma ^2 log^2(π))/103680000 + (12019 gamma ^3 log^2(π))/5184000 - (137 gamma ^4 log^2(π))/345600 + ( gamma ^5 log^2(π))/28800 - (58067611 i π log^2(π))/6220800000 + (874853 i gamma π log^2(π))/103680000 - (12019 i gamma ^2 π log^2(π))/3456000 + (137 i gamma ^3 π log^2(π))/172800 - (i gamma ^4 π log^2(π))/11520 + (874853 π^2 log^2(π))/1244160000 - (12019 gamma π^2 log^2(π))/20736000 + (137 gamma ^2 π^2 log^2(π))/691200 - ( gamma ^3 π^2 log^2(π))/34560 - (12019 i π^3 log^2(π))/41472000 + (137 i gamma π^3 log^2(π))/691200 - (i gamma ^2 π^3 log^2(π))/23040 + (137 π^4 log^2(π))/9216000 - ( gamma π^4 log^2(π))/153600 - (19 i π^5 log^2(π))/2764800 + (58067611 log^3(π))/9331200000 - (874853 gamma log^3(π))/155520000 + (12019 gamma ^2 log^3(π))/5184000 - (137 gamma ^3 log^3(π))/259200 + ( gamma ^4 log^3(π))/17280 + (874853 i π log^3(π))/311040000 - (12019 i gamma π log^3(π))/5184000 + (137 i gamma ^2 π log^3(π))/172800 - (i gamma ^3 π log^3(π))/8640 - (12019 π^2 log^3(π))/62208000 + (137 gamma π^2 log^3(π))/1036800 - ( gamma ^2 π^2 log^3(π))/34560 + (137 i π^3 log^3(π))/2073600 - (i gamma π^3 log^3(π))/34560 - (π^4 log^3(π))/460800 - (874853 log^4(π))/622080000 + (12019 gamma log^4(π))/10368000 - (137 gamma ^2 log^4(π))/345600 + ( gamma ^3 log^4(π))/17280 - (12019 i π log^4(π))/20736000 + (137 i gamma π log^4(π))/345600 - (i gamma ^2 π log^4(π))/11520 + (137 π^2 log^4(π))/4147200 - ( gamma π^2 log^4(π))/69120 - (i π^3 log^4(π))/138240 + (12019 log^5(π))/51840000 - (137 gamma log^5(π))/864000 + ( gamma ^2 log^5(π))/28800 + (137 i π log^5(π))/1728000 - (i gamma π log^5(π))/28800 - (π^2 log^5(π))/345600 - (137 log^6(π))/5184000 + ( gamma log^6(π))/86400 - (i π log^6(π))/172800 + (log^7(π))/604800 + (65588746609 (-(i π)/2 + log(π)))/100776960000000 + (226576032859 ((i π)/2 + log(π)))/11197440000000 + (226576032859 i Si(π))/5598720000000 + (69558361/6998400000 + (256103 (137/60 - gamma ))/233280000 - (296057 gamma )/29160000 + (12019 gamma ^2)/2592000 - (137 gamma ^3)/129600 + gamma ^4/8640 + (296057 i π)/58320000 - (12019 i gamma π)/2592000 + (137 i gamma ^2 π)/86400 - (i gamma ^3 π)/4320 - (12019 π^2)/31104000 + (137 gamma π^2)/518400 - ( gamma ^2 π^2)/17280 + (137 i π^3)/1036800 - (i gamma π^3)/17280 - π^4/230400 - (296057 log(π))/29160000 + (12019 gamma log(π))/1296000 - (137 gamma ^2 log(π))/43200 + ( gamma ^3 log(π))/2160 - (12019 i π log(π))/2592000 + (137 i gamma π log(π))/43200 - (i gamma ^2 π log(π))/1440 + (137 π^2 log(π))/518400 - ( gamma π^2 log(π))/8640 - (i π^3 log(π))/17280 + (12019 log^2(π))/2592000 - (137 gamma log^2(π))/43200 + ( gamma ^2 log^2(π))/1440 + (137 i π log^2(π))/86400 - (i gamma π log^2(π))/1440 - (π^2 log^2(π))/17280 - (137 log^3(π))/129600 + ( gamma log^3(π))/2160 - (i π log^3(π))/4320 + (log^4(π))/8640 - (256103 (-(i π)/2 + log(π)))/233280000) ζ(3) + ((-137/60 + gamma )/2160 + (-(i π)/2 + log(π))/2160) ζ(3)^2 + (12019/2160000 - (137 gamma )/36000 + gamma ^2/1200 + (137 i π)/72000 - (i gamma π)/1200 - π^2/14400 - (137 log(π))/36000 + 1/600 gamma log(π) - (i π log(π))/1200 + (log^2(π))/1200) ζ(5) + ζ(7)/840`

$\,^{9,0}_{8,9}$ code:

`-11008015293121/26873856000000000 + (816073489 (49/20 - gamma )^2)/14929920000000 + (39987600961 gamma )/149299200000000 + (532909451657 gamma ^2)/134369280000000 - (483900263 gamma ^3)/373248000000 + (68165041 gamma ^4)/223948800000 - (336581 gamma ^5)/6220800000 + (13489 gamma ^6)/1866240000 - (7 gamma ^7)/10368000 + gamma ^8/29030400 + 1/(1679616 π^6) + (1288991 i)/(656100000000 π^5) - 1802927233/(335923200000000 π^4) - (6367091071 i)/(335923200000000 π^3) + 94576236161/(671846400000000 π^2) + (5497117366741 i)/(671846400000000 π) + (4325716211663 i π)/537477120000000 - (532909451657 i gamma π)/134369280000000 + (483900263 i gamma ^2 π)/248832000000 - (68165041 i gamma ^3 π)/111974400000 + (336581 i gamma ^4 π)/2488320000 - (13489 i gamma ^5 π)/622080000 + (49 i gamma ^6 π)/20736000 - (i gamma ^7 π)/7257600 - (503530806053 π^2)/1612431360000000 + (483900263 gamma π^2)/1492992000000 - (68165041 gamma ^2 π^2)/447897600000 + (336581 gamma ^3 π^2)/7464960000 - (13489 gamma ^4 π^2)/1492992000 + (49 gamma ^5 π^2)/41472000 - ( gamma ^6 π^2)/12441600 + (483900263 i π^3)/2985984000000 - (68165041 i gamma π^3)/447897600000 + (336581 i gamma ^2 π^3)/4976640000 - (13489 i gamma ^3 π^3)/746496000 + (49 i gamma ^4 π^3)/16588800 - (i gamma ^5 π^3)/4147200 - (68165041 π^4)/5971968000000 + (336581 gamma π^4)/33177600000 - (13489 gamma ^2 π^4)/3317760000 + (49 gamma ^3 π^4)/55296000 - ( gamma ^4 π^4)/11059200 + (6395039 i π^5)/597196800000 - (256291 i gamma π^5)/29859840000 + (931 i gamma ^2 π^5)/331776000 - (19 i gamma ^3 π^5)/49766400 - (152233 π^6)/358318080000 + (553 gamma π^6)/1990656000 - (79 gamma ^2 π^6)/1393459200 + (77 i π^7)/159252480 - (11 i gamma π^7)/55738368 - (2339 π^8)/334430208000 - (816073489 (-5369/3600 + π^2/6))/14929920000000 - (5497117366741 Ci(π))/671846400000000 + (270127056529 i π _3 F_3(1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2;i π))/33592320000000 - (483900263 i π _4 F_4(1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/62208000000 + (68165041 i π _5 F_5(1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/9331200000 - (336581 i π _6 F_6(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/51840000 + (13489 i π _7 F_7(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/2592000 - (49 i π _8 F_8(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π))/14400 + 1/720 i π _9 F_9(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2;i π) + (5497117366741 (-(i π)/2 - log(π)))/1343692800000000 + (11354123142131 log(π))/1343692800000000 + (532909451657 gamma log(π))/67184640000000 - (483900263 gamma ^2 log(π))/124416000000 + (68165041 gamma ^3 log(π))/55987200000 - (336581 gamma ^4 log(π))/1244160000 + (13489 gamma ^5 log(π))/311040000 - (49 gamma ^6 log(π))/10368000 + ( gamma ^7 log(π))/3628800 - (532909451657 i π log(π))/134369280000000 + (483900263 i gamma π log(π))/124416000000 - (68165041 i gamma ^2 π log(π))/37324800000 + (336581 i gamma ^3 π log(π))/622080000 - (13489 i gamma ^4 π log(π))/124416000 + (49 i gamma ^5 π log(π))/3456000 - (i gamma ^6 π log(π))/1036800 + (483900263 π^2 log(π))/1492992000000 - (68165041 gamma π^2 log(π))/223948800000 + (336581 gamma ^2 π^2 log(π))/2488320000 - (13489 gamma ^3 π^2 log(π))/373248000 + (49 gamma ^4 π^2 log(π))/8294400 - ( gamma ^5 π^2 log(π))/2073600 - (68165041 i π^3 log(π))/447897600000 + (336581 i gamma π^3 log(π))/2488320000 - (13489 i gamma ^2 π^3 log(π))/248832000 + (49 i gamma ^3 π^3 log(π))/4147200 - (i gamma ^4 π^3 log(π))/829440 + (336581 π^4 log(π))/33177600000 - (13489 gamma π^4 log(π))/1658880000 + (49 gamma ^2 π^4 log(π))/18432000 - ( gamma ^3 π^4 log(π))/2764800 - (256291 i π^5 log(π))/29859840000 + (931 i gamma π^5 log(π))/165888000 - (19 i gamma ^2 π^5 log(π))/16588800 + (553 π^6 log(π))/1990656000 - (79 gamma π^6 log(π))/696729600 - (11 i π^7 log(π))/55738368 + (532909451657 log^2(π))/134369280000000 - (483900263 gamma log^2(π))/124416000000 + (68165041 gamma ^2 log^2(π))/37324800000 - (336581 gamma ^3 log^2(π))/622080000 + (13489 gamma ^4 log^2(π))/124416000 - (49 gamma ^5 log^2(π))/3456000 + ( gamma ^6 log^2(π))/1036800 + (483900263 i π log^2(π))/248832000000 - (68165041 i gamma π log^2(π))/37324800000 + (336581 i gamma ^2 π log^2(π))/414720000 - (13489 i gamma ^3 π log^2(π))/62208000 + (49 i gamma ^4 π log^2(π))/1382400 - (i gamma ^5 π log^2(π))/345600 - (68165041 π^2 log^2(π))/447897600000 + (336581 gamma π^2 log^2(π))/2488320000 - (13489 gamma ^2 π^2 log^2(π))/248832000 + (49 gamma ^3 π^2 log^2(π))/4147200 - ( gamma ^4 π^2 log^2(π))/829440 + (336581 i π^3 log^2(π))/4976640000 - (13489 i gamma π^3 log^2(π))/248832000 + (49 i gamma ^2 π^3 log^2(π))/2764800 - (i gamma ^3 π^3 log^2(π))/414720 - (13489 π^4 log^2(π))/3317760000 + (49 gamma π^4 log^2(π))/18432000 - ( gamma ^2 π^4 log^2(π))/1843200 + (931 i π^5 log^2(π))/331776000 - (19 i gamma π^5 log^2(π))/16588800 - (79 π^6 log^2(π))/1393459200 - (483900263 log^3(π))/373248000000 + (68165041 gamma log^3(π))/55987200000 - (336581 gamma ^2 log^3(π))/622080000 + (13489 gamma ^3 log^3(π))/93312000 - (49 gamma ^4 log^3(π))/2073600 + ( gamma ^5 log^3(π))/518400 - (68165041 i π log^3(π))/111974400000 + (336581 i gamma π log^3(π))/622080000 - (13489 i gamma ^2 π log^3(π))/62208000 + (49 i gamma ^3 π log^3(π))/1036800 - (i gamma ^4 π log^3(π))/207360 + (336581 π^2 log^3(π))/7464960000 - (13489 gamma π^2 log^3(π))/373248000 + (49 gamma ^2 π^2 log^3(π))/4147200 - ( gamma ^3 π^2 log^3(π))/622080 - (13489 i π^3 log^3(π))/746496000 + (49 i gamma π^3 log^3(π))/4147200 - (i gamma ^2 π^3 log^3(π))/414720 + (49 π^4 log^3(π))/55296000 - ( gamma π^4 log^3(π))/2764800 - (19 i π^5 log^3(π))/49766400 + (68165041 log^4(π))/223948800000 - (336581 gamma log^4(π))/1244160000 + (13489 gamma ^2 log^4(π))/124416000 - (49 gamma ^3 log^4(π))/2073600 + ( gamma ^4 log^4(π))/414720 + (336581 i π log^4(π))/2488320000 - (13489 i gamma π log^4(π))/124416000 + (49 i gamma ^2 π log^4(π))/1382400 - (i gamma ^3 π log^4(π))/207360 - (13489 π^2 log^4(π))/1492992000 + (49 gamma π^2 log^4(π))/8294400 - ( gamma ^2 π^2 log^4(π))/829440 + (49 i π^3 log^4(π))/16588800 - (i gamma π^3 log^4(π))/829440 - (π^4 log^4(π))/11059200 - (336581 log^5(π))/6220800000 + (13489 gamma log^5(π))/311040000 - (49 gamma ^2 log^5(π))/3456000 + ( gamma ^3 log^5(π))/518400 - (13489 i π log^5(π))/622080000 + (49 i gamma π log^5(π))/3456000 - (i gamma ^2 π log^5(π))/345600 + (49 π^2 log^5(π))/41472000 - ( gamma π^2 log^5(π))/2073600 - (i π^3 log^5(π))/4147200 + (13489 log^6(π))/1866240000 - (49 gamma log^6(π))/10368000 + ( gamma ^2 log^6(π))/1036800 + (49 i π log^6(π))/20736000 - (i gamma π log^6(π))/1036800 - (π^2 log^6(π))/12441600 - (7 log^7(π))/10368000 + ( gamma log^7(π))/3628800 - (i π log^7(π))/7257600 + (log^8(π))/29030400 - (816073489 (49/20 - gamma ) (-(i π)/2 + log(π)))/7464960000000 + (816073489 (-(i π)/2 + log(π))^2)/14929920000000 - (5497117366741 ((i π)/2 + log(π)))/1343692800000000 - (5497117366741 i Si(π))/671846400000000 + (-533180263/279936000000 - (28567 (49/20 - gamma )^2)/311040000 + (27783497 gamma )/13996800000 - (154007 gamma ^2)/155520000 + (13489 gamma ^3)/46656000 - (49 gamma ^4)/1036800 + gamma ^5/259200 - (27783497 i π)/27993600000 + (154007 i gamma π)/155520000 - (13489 i gamma ^2 π)/31104000 + (49 i gamma ^3 π)/518400 - (i gamma ^4 π)/103680 + (32291 π^2)/622080000 - (13489 gamma π^2)/186624000 + (49 gamma ^2 π^2)/2073600 - ( gamma ^3 π^2)/311040 - (13489 i π^3)/373248000 + (49 i gamma π^3)/2073600 - (i gamma ^2 π^3)/207360 + (49 π^4)/27648000 - ( gamma π^4)/1382400 - (19 i π^5)/24883200 + (28567 (-5369/3600 + π^2/6))/311040000 + (27783497 log(π))/13996800000 - (154007 gamma log(π))/77760000 + (13489 gamma ^2 log(π))/15552000 - (49 gamma ^3 log(π))/259200 + ( gamma ^4 log(π))/51840 + (154007 i π log(π))/155520000 - (13489 i gamma π log(π))/15552000 + (49 i gamma ^2 π log(π))/172800 - (i gamma ^3 π log(π))/25920 - (13489 π^2 log(π))/186624000 + (49 gamma π^2 log(π))/1036800 - ( gamma ^2 π^2 log(π))/103680 + (49 i π^3 log(π))/2073600 - (i gamma π^3 log(π))/103680 - (π^4 log(π))/1382400 - (154007 log^2(π))/155520000 + (13489 gamma log^2(π))/15552000 - (49 gamma ^2 log^2(π))/172800 + ( gamma ^3 log^2(π))/25920 - (13489 i π log^2(π))/31104000 + (49 i gamma π log^2(π))/172800 - (i gamma ^2 π log^2(π))/17280 + (49 π^2 log^2(π))/2073600 - ( gamma π^2 log^2(π))/103680 - (i π^3 log^2(π))/207360 + (13489 log^3(π))/46656000 - (49 gamma log^3(π))/259200 + ( gamma ^2 log^3(π))/25920 + (49 i π log^3(π))/518400 - (i gamma π log^3(π))/25920 - (π^2 log^3(π))/311040 - (49 log^4(π))/1036800 + ( gamma log^4(π))/51840 - (i π log^4(π))/103680 + (log^5(π))/259200 + (28567 (49/20 - gamma ) (-(i π)/2 + log(π)))/155520000 - (28567 (-(i π)/2 + log(π))^2)/311040000) ζ(3) + ((49/20 - gamma )^2/25920 + π^2/77760 + (5369/3600 - π^2/6)/25920 + ((-49/20 + gamma ) (-(i π)/2 + log(π)))/12960 + (-(i π)/2 + log(π))^2/25920) ζ(3)^2 + (-336581/259200000 + (13489 gamma )/12960000 - (49 gamma ^2)/144000 + gamma ^3/21600 - (13489 i π)/25920000 + (49 i gamma π)/144000 - (i gamma ^2 π)/14400 + (49 π^2)/1728000 - ( gamma π^2)/86400 - (i π^3)/172800 + (13489 log(π))/12960000 - (49 gamma log(π))/72000 + ( gamma ^2 log(π))/7200 + (49 i π log(π))/144000 - (i gamma π log(π))/7200 - (π^2 log(π))/86400 - (49 log^2(π))/144000 + ( gamma log^2(π))/7200 - (i π log^2(π))/14400 + (log^3(π))/21600) ζ(5) + (ζ(3) ζ(5))/10800 + (-7/14400 + gamma /5040 - (i π)/10080 + log(π)/5040) ζ(7)`

This is the limit of what my tablet can do, so I will stop here. Notice that the Meijer G functions really can be simplified into the following, so notice patterns above:

- $\ln^k(\pi),k\in\Bbb N$
- Riemann Zeta functions
- Increasingly complicated rational number coefficients
- Hypergeometric function terms in the form of $\,_p \text F_p(a,…,a;b,…,b;\pi i);a,b\in\Bbb N$
- $\pi^k,k\in\Bbb N$
- Arithmetic Operations
- The Euler-Mascheroni constant in the form of $γ^k,k\in\Bbb N$
- The Imaginary unit
- $\text{Ci}(\pi)$
- The [Wilbraham-Gibbs constant: $\text G’$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilbraham-GibbsConstant.html) $\text G’=\text{Si}(\pi)$

Let’s assume that products like $\prod\limits_{n=5}^4 f(n)=1$ based on [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_5%5E4+f%28n%29), but help is wanted in which convention should be used.

Codes:
`MeijerG[{{Subscript[a, 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[a, n]}, {Subscript[a, n + 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[a, p]}}, {{Subscript[b, 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[b, m]}, {Subscript[b, m + 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[b, q]}}, z] == Sum[((Product[If[j == k, 1, Gamma[Subscript[b, j] - Subscript[b, k]]], {j, 1, m}] Product[Gamma[1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[a, j]], {j, 1, n}])/(Product[Gamma[Subscript[a, j] - Subscript[b, k]], {j, n + 1, p}] Product[Gamma[1 - Subscript[b, j] + Subscript[b, k]], {j, m + 1, q}])) z^Subscript[b, k] HypergeometricPFQ[ {1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[a, 1], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[a, p]}, {1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[b, 1], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[b, k - 1], 1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[b, k + 1], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[b, k] - Subscript[b, q]}, (-1)^(p - m - n) z], {k, 1, m}] /; (p < q || (p == q && m + n > p) || (p == q && m + n == p && Abs[z] < 1)) && ForAll[{j, k}, Element[{j, k}, Integers] && j != k && 1 <= j <= m && 1 <= k <= m, !Element[Subscript[b, j] - Subscript[b, k], Integers]]`

`MeijerG[{{Subscript[a, 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[a, n]}, {Subscript[a, n + 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[a, p]}}, {{Subscript[b, 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[b, m]}, {Subscript[b, m + 1], \[Ellipsis], Subscript[b, q]}}, z] == Sum[((Product[If[j == k, 1, Gamma[Subscript[a, k] - Subscript[a, j]]], {j, 1, n}] Product[Gamma[1 + Subscript[b, j] - Subscript[a, k]], {j, 1, m}])/(Product[Gamma[Subscript[a, k] - Subscript[b, j]], {j, m + 1, q}] Product[Gamma[1 + Subscript[a, j] - Subscript[a, k]], {j, n + 1, p}])) z^(Subscript[a, k] - 1) HypergeometricPFQ[ {1 + Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[a, k], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[b, q] - Subscript[a, k]}, {1 + Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, k], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[a, k - 1] - Subscript[a, k], 1 + Subscript[a, k + 1] - Subscript[a, k], \[Ellipsis], 1 + Subscript[a, p] - Subscript[a, k]}, (-1)^(q - m - n)/z], {k, 1, n}] /; (p > q || (p == q && m + n == p + 1 && !IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-1, 0}], z]) || (p == q && m + n > p + 1) || (p == q && m + n == p && Abs[z] > 1)) && ForAll[{j, k}, Element[{j, k}, Integers] && j != k && 1 <= j <= n && 1 <= k <= n, !Element[Subscript[a, j] - Subscript[a, k], Integers]]`

from [this Wolfram Functions source](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/26/01/02/).

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns Let me experiment a bit more with this. Also note that I wrote “ where $b_h-b_{n+2}+1,h\ne n+2$“ which is part of the formula in the first few edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131679/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-marvin-ray-burns).

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns   Here is the code above in the question. I would start by finding the hypergeometric terms as a pattern.

Comment: I got the same thing using FunctionExpand[]. Thank you sooooo much!!!

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns Please tell me if there is a pattern for the general case, probably in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: I might get to that tonight going into tomorrow. I'm presently checking the results numerically, which gives some strange results as far as precision vs accuracy are concerned: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2412947

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns One small idea might be when you said:” I might be missing more, but I see I'm missing the input for n. How should I add it?”, maybe try $n=5$ or some other number manually to see if there is a pattern. The most recent wolfram community post is a bit confusing, so what is the main problem, I guess the partial sums are very small?

Comment: I almost had the pattern found, but made a critical error. I'm sure it is a pattern though.

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns Please tell me when you fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll let you know when I get back to it. I do my best research by accident.

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns Out of curiosity, have you found anything?

Comment: I hate leaving you hanging, but knowing there exists a pattern suffices my curiosity for the moment, while I make new breakthroughs, cf https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628 . Eventually, I will use the pattern to see if I can compute the digits of that number better, and maybe even see if there exists a closed form for it!

Comment: To all: as a side note, [integrals in the form of $\int e^{-t} \ln^n(t)dt$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+e%5E%28-t%29+ln%28t%29%5E5) have $\,_n\text F_n(1,…,1:2,…,2;t)$ in their closed form seen in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

$$M2=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{i}{\pi }\right)^{1-n}\left(\text G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(^{1;\underbrace {1,…,1}_n}_{1-n,0; \underbrace {0,…,0}_n}\bigg|-\pi i\right)\right).
$$

$$CMRB\thickapprox\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{\pi }\right)^{1-n}\left(\text G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(^{1;\underbrace {1,…,1}_n}_{1-n,0; \underbrace {0,…,0}_n}\bigg|\pi csch^2(370/273)\right)\right)
.$$
Closer still:
$$CMRB\thickapprox\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{\pi }\right)^{1-n}\left(\text G_{n+1,n+2}^{n+2,0}\left(^{1;\underbrace {1,…,1}_n}_{1-n,0; \underbrace {0,…,0}_n}\bigg|\pi csch^2(370/273)\right)\right)-\frac{\frac{5 \zeta (3)}{49}+\frac{9 \pi }{5}}{10^{11}}
.$$

In Mathematica:

```
CMRB - Table[Sum[Pi^(n - 1)*f[n], {n, 1, x}], {x, 1,18}] - ((5*Zeta[3])/49 + (9*Pi)/5)/10^11
```

Out[119]= {0.0804780779739663286222710940165737883237, 
0.0260950162762931257068842761032688030041, 
0.0067510963494559934609016612807180221284, 
0.0014476338998533471551912455134999059581, 
0.0002645675640949217195085430052601079962, 
0.0000420881530812856081367149341809520137,
5.9242296961493730924897574880435068*10^-6,
7.474864537103224059973790031295736*10^-7,
8.54407538462824222942059320721107*10^-8,
8.9251325888879457250267879224470*10^-9,
8.583059968702843821551225271020*10^-10,
7.64650283532022577592229496193*10^-11,
6.3447547837009397882010087195*10^-12,
4.926421390518856574729455427*10^-13,
3.59415965161849728913056491*10^-14,
2.4728219944008976039834039*10^-15,
1.609783292469090322295807*10^-16, 9.9610889917417768160299*10^-18,
6.042280671694660016411*10^-19, 5.28800456493600471973*10^-20,
2.19087872234730798254*10^-20}

Comment: What is the goal of this answer, maybe a similar CMRB sum?

Comment: In https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628 that was the next logical step for me.